# How to decide between Dipole and Monopole antenna for Cubesat Uplink (433 MHz)?

Tags: antenna, dipole, satellites, feed-line

1. We are currently deciding between a dipole and a monopole for uplink (435MHz) , while the monopole is easier to feed, we are unsure of how effectively we'll be able to implement the ground plane, while the ground plane won't be needed for dipole antenna, we are unsure on how to feed them.
2. In many of dipoles in cubesats we have seen so far the elements of the dipoles are placed on opposite ends of the cubesat, this means that feeding points of both elements of the dipole is separated by about 10cm. In this situation, how exactly do we feed the dipole, since using a coax, and then using connecting wires, wouldn't the wires themselves contribute to the length of the antenna?

Also, what other parameters should we consider while deciding which antenna to use?

Comment: You're designing a satellite. "We are unsure how to" quite clearly means one thing: **You need to research that**. I don't see how us helping you to pick one antenna or the other is of any benefit because you'd still be missing all the necessary knowledge on antenna systems. So, sorry, your question sounds to me "we don't even understand the basics of antennas, but we're putting one in space where we can't fix it, for many thousand euros. Come fix our lack of research!", and that won't work out for your many thousand euros, I'm afraid.

Comment: Hi Rishabh and welcome to the site! You should check out this [answer to a similar question](https://ham.stackexchange.com/a/6907/1550), recommending how to model your antenna so you can make an informed & intelligent decision based on your cubesat need. I suspect this will help drive specificity with your question.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I think asking here is part of their research.

Comment: Great job @webmarc finding the related question!

Comment: @rclocher3 but then this is not a point at which they should be asking, because it's too broad to be answerable.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I agree that they have asked too early.  Maybe the related question will help them realize the direction they need to go.